# How to disable logs in Kedro

Tags: python, kedro

I have been unsuccessful in disabling kedro logs.  I have tried adding `disable_existing_loggers: True` to the logging.yml file as well as `disable:True` to all of the existing logs and it still appears to be saving log files.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `kedro` to stop logging you can override the `_setup_logging` in `ProjectContext` in `src/<package-name>/run.py` as per the [documentation](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/04_user_guide/07_logging.html#configure-logging). For example:

```
class ProjectContext(KedroContext):
    """Users can override the remaining methods from the parent class here, or create new ones
    (e.g. as required by plugins)

    """

    project_name = "<PACKGE-NAME>"
    project_version = "0.15.4"

    def _get_pipelines(self) -> Dict[str, Pipeline]:
        return create_pipelines()

    def _setup_logging(self) -> None:
        import logging
        logging.disable()
```

If you want it to still log to the console, but not save to `logs/info.log` then you can do `def _setup_logging(self) -> None: pass`.

Comment: This works, thanks for the help.  **NOTE** that you have to supply a logging level to `logging.disable`

Comment: Hmm, in mine I don't. It defaults to `CRITICAL`.